# rspamd and Apache reverse proxy: navigation does not work (fragments in URL have no effect)

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2, rspamd, unix-sockets

I have set up Apache 2.4.57 and Rspamd 3.6 on Ubuntu 23.10. I have configured Apache as a reverse proxy to the controller worker of Rspamd. I can access to Web UI of Rspamd, enter a password and I also see the main page, but I cannot navigate. Whenever I click on any of the links in the menu ("Status", "Throuput", "Configuration", ...) nothing changes.

What did I do wrong in my configuration?

rspamd configuration:

```
root@h2917298:~ # cat /etc/rspamd/override.d/worker-controller.inc 
password = "<my-pwd-hash>"
enable_password = "<my-pwd-hash>"
bind_socket = "/var/run/rspamd/controller.sock mode=0770";
```

Apache configuration:

```
root@h2917298:~ # cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/my-host.my-domain.tld.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName my-host.my-domain.tld
  ServerAdmin admin@my-domain.tld

  Redirect 308 / https://my-host.my-domain.tld/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName my-host.my-domain.tld
  ServerAdmin admin@my-domain.tld
  DocumentRoot /var/www/my-host.my-domain.tld/

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-host.my-domain.tld/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-host.my-domain.tld/privkey.pem
  SSLCACertificatePath  /etc/ssl/certs/

  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31104000; includeSubDomains"

  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </FilesMatch>
  <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory>

  ProxyPass         /rspamd  unix:/var/run/rspamd/controller.sock|http://localhost/
  ProxyPassReverse  /rspamd  unix:/var/run/rspamd/controller.sock|http://localhost/
</VirtualHost>
```

Groups for `www-data` (to allow access to socket):

```
root@h2917298:~ # groups www-data
www-data : www-data redis _rspamd
```

Navigation inside the WebUI of Rspamd does not work. The following URLs all lead to the same front page:

- `https://my-host.my-domain.tld/rspamd/`
- `https://my-host.my-domain.tld/rspamd/#status`
- `https://my-host.my-domain.tld/rspamd/#throughput`
- `https://my-host.my-domain.tld/rspamd/#configuration`
- `https://my-host.my-domain.tld/rspamd/#symbols`
- `https://my-host.my-domain.tld/rspamd/#scan`
- `https://my-host.my-domain.tld/rspamd/#selectors`
- `https://my-host.my-domain.tld/rspamd/#history`

I do not see any errors in the logs. The Web-UI of rspamd seems to use client-side navigation as it use URL fragments which are not sent to the server. Hence, I somehow doubt that there is a server-side misconfiguration.

Nontheless, navigation does not work.